# group form controls in Access 2010

Tags: ms-access-2010

I have a database created in Access 2003 which I've moved over to Access 2010. I've added some new form controls and can't figure out how to group them together on the form like the Format -> Group function in Access 2003. Does this exist anymore? If not, is there a work around?

Thanks,

Ed

Answer (score 0):

The best I was able to find is to highlight the controls, go to the arrange menu, go to Size/Space and you should see group in there.